# In Python, are mixins equivalent to composition? If so, then why not just use composition?

Tags: python, inheritance, mixins, composition

I understand mixin as what looks like inheritance but what is more like composition.
(edit: I tend to think `giving additional functionality/attributes` by mixin rather than `giving another is-a relationship`.)
Mentally, I'm saying something like this when I use mixin: I'm giving you this mixin you are missing, rather than you are actually this mixin-type as well.(is-a)

And I read few times, you should prefer composition over inheritance.

We could just use straight compositions instead of mixins, what is mixin for?

If I have to guess, it's because my_instance.foo() is easier than my_instance.another_instance.foo()?
(You can use my_instance.foo() if mixin has foo(), you need my_instance.another_instance.foo() when you composite another_instance as an attribute of my_instance)

Are there any other reason?

---

Edit:

So even though I feel it's has-a, mixin is still is-a relationship. and benefit you get when you use is-a here is, cleaner interface. That' how I interpret delnan's answer.

Comment: Mixin is just a different name for multiple inheritance, not for composition. Actually you should say "sensible multiple inheritance" since mixin classes are *designed* to be used with multiple inheritance. I don't really see where mixin provide an has-a relationship vs is-a. By the way: using `__getattr__` it's trivial to be able to do `my_instance.foo()` instead of `my_instance.another_instance.foo()` (and please, note that for PEP8 instance attributes should have `names_with_lowercase_with_underscores`, not `semiCamelCase`)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> (Since mixin doesn't give you is-a relationship, it gives you has-a)

Wrong, it does give you a is-a relationship. Consider `class C(A, B)`. `issubclass(C, A)` is true and so is `issubclass(C, B)`. The call `C().method_of_B()` calls the method of B if it isn't overridden somewhere in the MRO (which can happen with single inheritance too!), and similarly for methods of `A`. The attribute access `C().attr_of_{a,b}` gives you an attribute of `A` or `B` too (same caveat as with methods).

> And I read few times, you should prefer composition over inheritance.

This rule of thumb exists because many people tend to use inheritance where it isn't appropriate, not because inheritance isn't a useful tool in any case. This applies to Python too. Common (good) reasons include:

- A is-a relationship would be wrong, for example because it breaks the Liskov Substitution Principle. This reason is not affected by mixins, see above.
- Composition is easier or less error-prone, for various reasons. This reason is valid when mixins are possible too, if anything it's amplified as it can be a bit tricky ([though not impossible](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)) to get the MRO and sequence of `super()` calls right.

> If I have to guess, it's because my_instance.foo() is easier than my_instance.another_instance.foo()?

That's just a few additional characters. More important is that you have to re-type wrapper methods for every single method you want to re-export (which would be *all* of them if you're emulating an is-a relationship via composition).

More conceptually, this manual work seems pointless and error-prone if `C` really is-a `A`. Mixins/multiple inheritance support the case where an object is more than what can or should be represented by a single bass class. For example, a UTF-8 string may be both a `ByteBuffer` and a `UnicodeStream`. In general, we have interfaces for this (or not; in Python this is implicit), but mixins also allow adding related functionality in a composable and convenient manner.

Comment: `Wrong, it does give you a is-a relationship.` OK. I didn't write it clearly. Let me rephrase: Mixin feels more like has-a instead of is-a because it gives a functionality which an original class misses.

Comment: @eugene I think I see where you're coming from, but I don't think that's a useful way to think about it. There is no one "original class". There are a couple of base classes, and the derived class inherits some bits from each of the base classes.

Comment: What can be misleading, is if you think "my class *has a* behavior", and based on the words "has a", you mistakenly think you're using composition. The property of having a behavior is (more or less) the definition of "is a", which makes it inheritance. When you try formulating a sentence to describe a *specific* behavior, you get something like "my class *has a* duck", which sounds wrong, because it is - if my class "quacks like a duck", then of course, "my class *is a* duck", which makes it (multiple) inheritance, not composition.

Comment: now I read it after a year after, Can I read it as.. "compositing behavior" = "mixin" (and it is inheritance not composition) ?