# Sklearn fitting SVM with StandardScaler

Tags: python, scikit-learn

please am fitting svr on my dataset and am getting this error message. it was working when I have not included standardscaler. I have tried all means but still not working.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc_X = StandardScaler()
sc_y = StandardScaler()
X = sc_X.fit_transform(X)
y = sc_y.fit_transform(np.array(y).reshape(1,-1))

from sklearn.svm import SVR
regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf')
regressor.fit(X,y)`

    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-75416c35e495> in <module>
      2 from sklearn.svm import SVR
      3 regressor = SVR(kernel = 'rbf') # rbf means radial basis function
----> 4 regressor.fit(X,y)

C:\anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    146         X, y = check_X_y(X, y, dtype=np.float64,
    147                          order='C', accept_sparse='csr',
--> 148                          accept_large_sparse=False)
    149         y = self._validate_targets(y)
    150 

C:\anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
    758                         dtype=None)
    759     else:
--> 760         y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
    761         _assert_all_finite(y)
    762     if y_numeric and y.dtype.kind == 'O':

C:\anconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in column_or_1d(y, warn)
    795         return np.ravel(y)
    796 
--> 797     raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
    798 
    799 

ValueError: bad input shape (1, 10)
```

Comment: You just want to fit X. Not X and y. Transformers aren't made to have a predictor argument (y). See more in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54899803/4590385

Answer (score 0):

You are feeding to the SVM a target vector with dimension (1,10) which means one row and ten columns, this is wrong and it's caused by you're using of reshaping in

```
y = sc_y.fit_transform(np.array(y).reshape(1,-1))
```

Please note that this line is also conceptually wrong, the standardised should be applied only on the training features, not on the target vector, so you can avoid to define

```
sc_y = StandardScaler()
```

Comment: Glad that it worked! Feel free to upvote or accept the answer if it was helpful.